# How to scan all available SCSS files ans parse the comments to create informations into an array?

Tags: php, parsing, sass, comments, token

I have many SCSS files and want to make a style guide (a library with all components like buttons, forms, ...). This style guide should work automatically, so that when you create a new stylesheet it should automatically scan the comments and put the data into an array to create a dynamic information page about the new component.

At example:

```
/**
* @title title1
* @description description1
* @author author1
*/

.list {
   li {
       overflow: hidden;           
       border-bottom: cornflowerblue;
       margin: 0 0 4px 0;
   }

   a {
       text-decoration: none;
   }       
}
```

Now I want to parse this comment and want to get the word(s) after a.e. the @title Tag. So in this case I would like to get the word "title1" and automatically save it into an array.
My try was following:

```
$source = file_get_contents("mysite/examplestyles.scss");

$tokens = token_get_all($source);
$comment = array(
    T_COMMENT,
    T_DOC_COMMENT
);

foreach ($tokens as $token)
{
    if (!in_array($token[0], $comment))
    {
        continue;
    }

    $txt = $token[1];
}
```

How should I change my code sample to get the informations I would like to have?
It would be great if somebody can help me. I think it would be understandable if the ouput is the information I would like to get (title1, description1, author1) so a code sample would be nice to have.

If you have any questions you can ask me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're basically trying to re-invent [SassDoc](http://sassdoc.com/), but it is much better to use this solution